# Handling unexpected events in winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a `win-form` application developed in .net 4.0 and using `SQL 2008` as `DBMS`.

User can open an item from a list of item and every time they open, I am updating the database with the ***userId*** to state the particular item is opened by particular user so other users can’t open the same item at same time. Also when user closes the item I am resetting it back to normal where others can open.

But I am wondering how to update the database if some ones system got crashed/stuck or something similar. Is there any good solution to handle these kinds of situations?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to add a time stamp column into the data table. Every time a user accesses an item (in addition to other work) you set this time stamp value.

You can then have a separate task/service that iterates thought the records and releases any expired locks once in a while.

Comment: In this case I cannot set a generic timeout period for one item. So I don't wont to manually reset only if they exit from the system or it got stuck or close

Comment: You can possibly send a heart bit message every so often. If the heart bit has not been received - you know there is something wrong with the system.

Comment: Thanks oleksii, is it possible to identify the user and send the Heartbeat message? I tried something like this **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8349/Observing-Applications-via-Heartbeat**

Comment: Yeah it should be possible to do that. You may need to have a client-server application for that where client sends a heart beat message with its ID. Server records all the heart beat messages and removes clients that used graceful session shutdown. It is however quite a bit of work... You can possibly use WCF for this.

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to implement your own [locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29) mechanism. See how to mitigate the problems of [Deadlocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) that should give you an idea. Basically either you use notifications or stamps to track lock's owner status (if it's dead or still using the resource), preventing [resource starvation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_starvation).

**Requested example**

There are 2 users. User A and User B.

User A open a view within your app, then two things happen:

- You update the DB and set the stamp to the current time.
- You start a new background thread who will be responsible to mantain the lock. This background thread must wait N-Delta where N is the maximum minutes the resource can be locked without renew and delta is the delta for update time. So, for example, suppose a view can be locked for maximum 15 minutes without user activity, then your thread must wait 15-1 (taking that will probably take 1 minute to notify DB "better be caution with this time").

Then User B try to access to that view, you check on the db for the resource and for the lock table and if there's a lock on that view whose time isn't superior from 15 minutes then you deny access. BUT if time is most that 15 minutes you grant the access to the User B and remove the access from the User A.

If either User A or User B successfully close the view, then you just remove the entrance from the DB.

This is a very simple example but should give you an idea of what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you let me know how can I use notifications or stamps? any example will be great!!!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Sure buddie, see my edit. I'm trying to ordering my thougths. Sorry for language, english isn't my native language.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar situation before. In such cases you will have to assume how much maximum time would a user take to action on that item (say 15 mins). Create a table called item_lock with 2 columns: item_id, lock_aquired_time. Every time a user clicks on any item, a record would get inserted into this table. If any other user tries to open that item.. a notification would pop up on his screen that the resource is locked for actioning by XYZ. Futher you will need to create a service which would run say every minute and will remove any record which is older than 15 mins.
PS: Whenever any user has finished taking action on any item.. that row would get deleted from item_lock table.